# In Javascript, is A == !B always the same as A != B

Tags: javascript, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Refactoring some old code, I found the following:

```
someVar == !otherVar
```

That doesn't look that legible, I thought that could be written as:

```
someVar != otherVar
```

It seems logic to do so. But, since this is Javascript, I'm afraid of collateral problems, so is this really ok?

Comment: What are the types/ranges of values in these variables?

Comment: @Amit Typically boolean, but I'm asking because it's not always the case. Imagine if they are Strings or something different.

Comment: `someVar != otherVar` is equivalent to `!(someVar == otherVar)`, everything else depends on `otherVar`.

Comment: @Bergi you got a point there. In terms of logic, I think I can negate the whole expression but not the comparison itself.

Comment: You can for boolean values, but not for other types. You would need some value for which casting to boolean and negating does invert the result of all comparisons with all the other values. That's pretty rare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the statements in themselves are very different. `!aVar` will force that var into a boolean value. e.g. `'!0'` = true, `'!1'` or any other number will be false.
Some other examples  `!''` = true `!'abc` = false.

`!=` does a lenient (in)equality comparisson, which depending on type conversions can have very different results.

e.g.

```
5 != 6 //true
5 == !6 //false -> !6 is forced to a boolean (6=true,!6 = false), for the comparisson 5 is cast to a boolean (true), so the comparisson nets false
5 != 5 //false
5 == !5 //false, but because the same reason as above !5 becomes true, etc.
```

Probably the old code you mentioned uses this exactly for the reason of boolifying the `otherVar`. If someVar already is a boolean, it would make sense to do so. For all other comparissons it would probably give the wrong results.

Comment: My fear was exactly that it was doing some sort of casting/boolifying the var and in that case I could be introducing a bug by refactoring it. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 6):

The answer is *no*.

```
Infinity == !NaN; // false
Infinity != NaN; // true

'abc' == !false; //false
'abc' != false; // true
```

Open up a console and check it for yourself. There are many more examples.

Comment: Please use snippets - instructing people to "check for themselves" is bad practice.

Comment: There you got @Azamantes ! Maybe an edge case, but that definitely could happen.

Comment: Also `{} != null` or maybe `[] != null`, or what about `null != false`, `1 != Infinity` etc. Now how about an explanation ?